# Why do I get an NPE when a nested Enum references a parent static member in its constructor?

Tags: java, static-initialization, initialization-order

Conditions to recreate (as far as I can tell):

1. nested enum references a parent static member
2. nested class
3. static member of parent class takes enum as an constructor argument to nested class
4. enum is referenced by an external class before anything else in the parent class

Run this code online:
https://repl.it/repls/PlushWorthlessNetworking

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Recreate {

  private static ArrayList FEATURES = new ArrayList();

  public enum Car {
    TESLA(FEATURES);
    Car(ArrayList l) { }
  }

  public static class Garage {
    final Car car;

    Garage(Car car) {
      this.car = car;
    }
  }

  public static Garage ONE_CAR_GARAGE = new Garage(Car.TESLA);
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // inclusion of this line causes the next line to NPE
    System.out.println(Recreate.Car.TESLA);

    System.out.println(Recreate.ONE_CAR_GARAGE.car.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: It prints `TESLA` for me

Comment: you can run this code here: https://repl.it/repls/PlushWorthlessNetworking

Comment: Include the complete stack trace; identify which line is throwing the exception; do not rely on online development environments, use a real IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ.

Comment: FWIW I can repro on Java 1.8.

Comment: @JimGarrison here's the complete stack trace: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Main.main(Recreate.java:31)

Comment: This is a very good question.

Comment: But please don't use raw types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what is happening:

1. The main method starts executing
2. You refer to `Recreate.Car.TESLA`
3. The classloader starts to load and initialize `enum Car`. As noted below, class `Recreate` is NOT yet loaded or initialized.
4. The initializer for `TESLA` refers to `FEATURES`
5. This causes class `Recreate` to be loaded and initialized
6. As part of static initialization of `Recreate`, Class `Garage` is loaded, intialized, and the instance `ONE_CAR_GARAGE` is created.

The problem here is that at this point, the construction of `enum Car` is not complete, and `Car.TESLA` has the value `null`.

Even though classes may be nested, it is not the case that nested classes are loaded and initialized as part of the outer class initialization.  They may look nested in the source but each and every class is independent.  Static nested classes are equivalent to top-level classes.  Non-static classes are also the same but have the ability to refer to members in the containing class via a hidden reference.

You can see for yourself if you run this in a debugger, put breakpoints in several places, and examine the stack at each breakpoint.

I tested/debugged this in Eclipse with the following code, with breakpoints set where indicated.  It's slightly different from your code but shouldn't behave differently:

```
public class Foo5
{
    static class Recreate {

        private static ArrayList FEATURES = new ArrayList();

        public  enum Car {
          TESLA(FEATURES);
          Car(ArrayList l) { 
              System.out.println("car"); // *** Breakpoint ***
          }
        }
        public static Garage ONE_CAR_GARAGE = new Garage(Car.TESLA);

        public static class Garage {
            final Car car;

            Garage(Car car) {
              this.car = car;  // *** Breakpoint ***
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Recreate.Car car = Recreate.Car.TESLA;
        System.out.println(Recreate.Car.TESLA);
        System.out.println(Recreate.ONE_CAR_GARAGE.car.toString());
    }   
}
```

The first breakpoint you will hit will be the one in the `Garage(Car car)` constructor. Examining the stack at that point you will see

```
Foo5$Recreate$Garage.<init>(Foo5$Recreate$Car) line: 23 
Foo5$Recreate.<clinit>() line: 17   
Foo5$Recreate$Car.<clinit>() line: 12   
Foo5.main(String[]) line: 29
```

So when the `Garage` constructor is called, it has not yet returned from creating `Car`.  This is dictated by the convoluted dependencies you have created between classes, so the solution is to untangle the dependencies.  How you do that will depend on your ultimate goals.

Comment: Though this is indeed what is happening at the online tool, but is this behavior specified in the JLS?

Comment: Yes, this is the way the language works.  I debugged this in Eclipse.  I will add the code I used and indicate where I set breakpoints.

Answer (score 2):

You have a hidden circular dependency that's confusing the JVM. Let's take a look at your code.

```
class Recreate {

  private static ArrayList FEATURES = new ArrayList();

  public enum Car {
    TESLA(FEATURES);
    Car(ArrayList l) { }
  }

  public static class Garage {
    final Car car;

    Garage(Car car) {
      this.car = car;
    }
  }

  public static Garage ONE_CAR_GARAGE = new Garage(Car.TESLA);
}
```

We'll also need a few snippets from a [page out of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).

> 12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure
>
> ...
>
> 9. Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the
>      class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they
>      were a single block.

So our static data is being initialized when it's first referenced. Now, your `Car.TESLA` is implicitly `static final`, but it's not a constant, as per [the definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression

So for our purposes, there are three static non-constant variables in play here: `FEATURES`, `TESLA`, and `ONE_CAR_GARAGE`.

Now, in your working case, you reference `Recreate.ONE_CAR_GARAGE`. This is a reference to a static field in `Recreate`, so `FEATURES` and then `ONE_CAR_GARAGE` get initialized. Then, *during* the initialization of `ONE_CAR_GARAGE`, `TESLA` gets initialized since its enumeration class is referenced. All's well.

However, if we reference the enum too early then we do things in the wrong order. `Recreate.Car.TESLA` gets referenced, so `TESLA` gets initialized. `TESLA` references `FEATURES`, so `Recreate` has to be initialized. This causes `FEATURES` and `ONE_CAR_GARAGE` to get initialized *before* `TESLA` finishes existing.

It's that hidden dependency that trips you up. `Recreate.Car` depends on `Recreate` which depends on `Recreate.Car`. Moving the `ONE_CAR_GARAGE` field into the `Garage` class will cause it to not get initialized with `FEATURES` and will fix your problem.

Comment: Wow, I think I learnt something new about static nested class.

Comment: I think it would be good to have a summary of what *can* and *cannot* be done when using nested classes.